# How to write a random array (with no spatial reference) to geotiff format?

Tags: arrays, matlab, geospatial, geotiff

The following MATLAB script generates random locations within a 300x400 array and codes those locations with values from 1-12.  **How can I convert this non-spatial array to a geotiff?** I hope to use the geotiff output to perform some trial analyses.  Any projected coordinate system (e.g. UTM) would do for this analysis.

I have tried using [`geotiffwrite()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/geotiffwrite.html) without success using the following implementation:

```
out = geotiffwrite('C:\path\to\file\test.tif', m)
```

Which yields the following error:

```
>> test
Error using geotiffwrite
Too many output arguments.
```

**EDIT:**

The main problem I am encountering is a lack of inputs into the `geotiffwrite()` function.  I am unsure how to deal with this problem. For example, I have no `A` or `R` variable because the array has no spatial reference.  As long as each pixel is georeferenced somewhere, I do not care what the spatial reference is.  The purpose of this is to create a sample dataset that I can experiment with using MATLAB spatial functions.

---

```
% Generate a totally black image to start with.
m = zeros(300, 400, 'uint8');

% Generate 1000 random locations.
numRandom = 1000;
linearIndices = randi(numel(m), 1, numRandom);

% Set those locations to be "white".
m(linearIndices) = randi(12, [numel(linearIndices) 1]);

% Display it.  Random locations will appear white.
image(m);
colormap(gray);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question has a very simple answer. Skip the `out`-variable when you call `geotiffwrite`. That is, use:

```
geotiffwrite('C:\path\to\file\test.tif', m)
```

Instead of

```
out = geotiffwrite('C:\path\to\file\test.tif', m)
```

This is example of a working code using `geotiffwrite`, taken from the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/map/ref/geotiffwrite.html). As you can see, there is no output variable there:

```
basename = 'boston_ovr';
imagefile = [basename '.jpg'];
RGB = imread(imagefile);
worldfile = getworldfilename(imagefile);
R = worldfileread(worldfile, 'geographic', size(RGB));
filename = [basename '.tif'];
geotiffwrite(filename, RGB, R)
figure
usamap(RGB, R)
geoshow(filename)
```

## Update:

According to the documentation, you need at least 3 input parameters. The correct syntax is:

```
geotiffwrite(filename,A,R)
geotiffwrite(filename,X,cmap,R)
geotiffwrite(...,Name,Value)
```

From documentation:

> `geotiffwrite(filename,A,R)` writes a georeferenced image or data grid,
>   `A`, spatially referenced by `R`, into an output file, `filename`.

Please visit [this link](http://www.mathworks.se/help/map/ref/geotiffwrite.html) to see how to use the function.

Comment: When I omitted the `out` variable, I received a "Not enough input arguments" error.

Comment: Great, thanks for the input.  Unfortunately the geotiffwrite() instructions do not provide much information on how to write an array (without a spatial reference) to geotiff format.

Comment: @Aaron, why do you want to do it? Are you sure `geotiff` is what you want?

Comment: Please see update to question. The purpose of this is to create a sample dataset that I can experiment with using Matlab spatial functions.